# spring batch retry not working with retrytemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I tried the spring batch retry in this example.
[Retry feature is not working in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047038/retry-feature-is-not-working-in-spring-batch) and it works.
I am trying to achieve the same with retrytemplate, but couldn't see the retry not working when thrown exception.

```
        @Configuration
            @EnableBatchProcessing
        //@EnableRetry
        public class RetryBatchJob {

          @Autowired
          private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

          @Autowired
          private StepBuilderFactory steps;

          @Bean
          public ItemReader<Integer> itemReader() {
            return new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
          }

          @Bean
          public ItemWriter<Integer> itemWriter() {
            return items -> {
              for (Integer item : items) {
                System.out.println("item = " + item);
                if (item.equals(7)) {
                  throw new Exception("Sevens are sometime nasty, let's retry them");
                }
              }
            };
          }

          @Bean
          public Step step() {
            return steps.get("step")
              .<Integer, Integer>chunk(2)
              .reader(itemReader())
              .writer(itemWriter())
              /*.faultTolerant()
              .retryLimit(5)
              .retry(Exception.class)*/
              .build();
          }

          @Bean  
          public Job job() {
            Job job = null;
            try {
              job = retryTemplate().execute(new RetryCallback<Job, Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public Job doWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws Throwable {
                  return jobs.get("job")
                    .start(step())
                    .build();
                }
              });
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
              throwable.printStackTrace();
            }
            return job;
          }

          public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RetryBatchJob.class);
            JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
            Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
            jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
          }

          @Bean
          public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
            RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();

            SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(5, singletonMap(Exception.class, true));
            retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(5);
            retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

            return retryTemplate;
          }

        }
```

Am I missing something when I use RetryTemplate? I tried declarative configuration on step and job methods too, but no luck.

```
@Retryable(value = {Exception.class},
 maxAttemptsExpression = "5"
)
```

Note: using spring-retry 1.2.2 RELEASE.

Answer (score 1):

Thrown exceptions during job execution do not stop the execution, the job continue until it returns the execution result either FAILED OR COMPLETED ... Which makes it a positive result for RetryTemplate.execute().
You can take advantage of the execution status returned to throw a runtimeException in case of failure.

```
RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();

    ExponentialBackOffPolicy exponentialBackOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    exponentialBackOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(5000);
    exponentialBackOffPolicy.setMultiplier(ExponentialBackOffPolicy.DEFAULT_MULTIPLIER);
    exponentialBackOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(ExponentialBackOffPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_INTERVAL);

    Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> exceptions = new HashMap<>();
    exceptions.put(Exception.class, true);
    SimpleRetryPolicy policy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(3, exceptions);

    template.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    template.setBackOffPolicy(exponentialBackOffPolicy);

    template.execute(new RetryCallback<JobExecution, Exception>() {

        @Override
        public JobExecution doWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws Exception {        
            return runJob(job, paramMap);
        }
    });
```

Function: runJob()

```
public JobExecution runJob(Job job, Map<String, JobParameter> paramMap) throws Exception {
    JobExecution exe = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters(paramMap));       
    if(exe.getStatus().equals(BatchStatus.FAILED))
        throw new RuntimeException(exe.toString());
    return exe;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `@Bean public Job job() { ... }` is intended to define a Spring Bean of type `Job`. According to your code, you are calling `retryTemplate().execute` inside this method and expecting the job to be retried. This is not correct.

What you can try is first define your job like:

```
@Bean  
public Job job() {
    return jobs.get("job")
                .start(step())
                .build();
}
```

then call the retry template on the job bean you get from the application context in the `main` method, something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RetryBatchJob.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = context.getBean(RetryTemplate.class);
        retryTemplate.execute(new RetryCallback<JobExecution, Exception>() {
            @Override
            public JobExecution doWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws Exception {
                return jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            };
        });
}
```

If I understand correctly, you are trying to automatically retry a failed job with a retry template, something similar to what is suggested in this PR: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/pull/440.

Anyway, I hope the example helps.

Comment: I tried your suggestion too calling the retrytemplate with application context, but the retry didn't happen when exception was thrown.

Comment: I had to add the check jobExecution.getStatus().equals(BatchStatus.FAILED) and throw a Custom Exception inside the doWithRetry-Method. After that change the retry worked as expected. MOURAD404 showed this solution in his answer.